# Can you use URL_Rewrite rewritemaps to modify ServerVariables in IIS?

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

So I'm having an issue and not sure if it's even possible.

Here's the scenario.  We utilize an F5 loadbalancer with an i-Rule set to send us a header (HTTP_IV-USER) value based on an access token.

We want to query that header, see if it matches a value we have setup in a rewritemap and then change it accordingly.

I haven't seen anyone doing this with servervariables.  It makes sense on how to do it in regards to changing an URL... but we'd like to change a header variable.

Basically we're taking the value from the Token, which is a number, and then matching that number to a username in active directory.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Of course, we can use rewritemap to check and replace the value. You could modify the rule below to achieve your requirement.

```
        <rewriteMaps>
            <rewriteMap name="StaticMap">
                <add key="aaaaaaaaa" value="bbbbbbbb" />
            </rewriteMap>
        </rewriteMaps>
        <outboundRules>
            <rule name="rewritemaprule">
                <match serverVariable="HTTP_IV-USER" pattern="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{StaticMap:{HTTP_IV-USER}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" value="{C:1}" />
            </rule>
        </outboundRules>
```